# Mono and stereo jacks

Tags: stereo, speakers, mono, computer

I want to hook up my computer to an amp, but I only have a mono cord at this point, and that has the 1/4 inch bit. If the 1/8 inch adapter was stereo, would the mono cord end up picking up all those signals to amplify?
Thanks!

Comment: It should cost much to get a 1/8 in TRS to ¼ TR on Amazon. Maybe Hosa sells something?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the best case scenario - you'll only get one good sounding mono channel. Stereo cords and adapters have two rings on their jack while mono only has one